# How to deal with an abusive adult daughter?

Tags: children

Assalam o alaikum.

I have a sister who is 34 years old and unmarried (I'll refer to her as Jane henceforth). Jane lives in the same house with our mother. My brother, along with his wife and three kids, also reside in the same house. My father passed away three years ago and my brother wants to stay in the same house with my widowed and aging mother.

I am married and have a child of my own (although I'm younger than Jane, and live in a different country). We have an older sister who is also married and has four children, and lives in the same country as them. Our youngest brother is studying abroad. I'm including all this information because I have a theory that Jane considers us all settled and happy in our respective lives, whereas she is not.

Jane has some serious issues. She hasn't finished school, never tried to finish it, and never went to university. The others have. Jane has been in and out of various administrative/ HR jobs. She's overweight (might even be obese) and has no hopes of finding a husband. My family has no objection to any man of her choice, save for the fact that he be muslim. She does face some gynaecological challenges but doctors have said she will get better only with marriage (or perhaps be barren).

Jane loves money and to live an extravagant lifestyle. But she's unqualified and hence can't find a job that offers her the salary she wants (in USD, she'd settle for nothing less than 3-4000).

Now because she isn't earning enough, she has gotten into the habit of looting people. She promises them jobs (as recruitment), gets money from them, never returns it or provides the job. She has several different techniques for taking people's money. She has been reported, people have filed cases against her. She has been taken into detention more than once for interrogation and has been locked up for days. She even owes us money, her family, which she had begged for in desperate times.

At home, she's extremely arrogant, disobedient, and abusive. She fights with all of us, even the kids. Towards our mother, she's extremely verbally abusive. Today, she even whacked our mum twice on the shoulder.

My brother says he's tired of having to deal with her and thinks my mum should disown her, under the Sharia law (they live in an Islamic country governed by the Sharia). I counter that although a major nuisance, she is still muslim, and believe she should either be admitted to a mental asylum or be punished in jail (20 years, 30 years, even lifetime, whatever). I fear she'll grow more physically abusive and oppress our mum (there might come a time when the others are not home, travelling, etc.).

Any advice is appreciated.